# What is the correct folder structure in Next.js for routes with query parameters?

Tags: next.js

Next.js already documents correct usage of nested api's in their documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) but one thing not covered there is the usage of query parameters. I have two routes. First one is `mysite.com/posts` which displays all the posts. Other one is `mysite.com/posts?id=12` where you only get to see that specific post. What could be the correct folder structure to place my js file in there?

Right now the folder structure I have is :

```
pages -- folder
 posts -- folder
  [id].js -- file
  index.js -- file
```

Even though I have a feeling that this should be the correct way it doesn't work. Whenever I hit  `mysite.com/posts?id=12`  I get `mysite.com/posts` and never get to see the page with the `id`. Any idea on what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `posts/index` will handle both `mysite.com/posts` and `mysite.com/posts?id=12`, the structure doesn't look at query params. To have something hit `posts/[id]` you'd need something like `mysite.com/posts/12`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass query parameter as per your folder structure i.e `mysite.com/posts/12`

As per documentation,Any route like `/post/1`, `/post/abc`, etc. will be matched by `pages/post/[id].js`. The matched path parameter will be sent as a query parameter to the page, and it will be merged with the other query parameters.

For example, the route `/post/abc` will have the following query object:

```
{ "id": "abc" }
```

Similarly, the route `/post/abc?foo=bar` will have the following query object:

```
{ "foo": "bar", "id": "abc" }
```

However, route parameters will override query parameters with the same name. For example, the route `/post/abc?id=123` will have the following query object:

```
{ "pid": "abc" }
```